# Strange exception when setting up ManyToOne relationship in Symfony 2 and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm getting the following exception when trying to update an entity:

```
The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class Proxies__CG__\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\TicketCategory. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "Proxies__CG__\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\TicketCategory" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Proxies__CG__\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\TicketCategory to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.
```

When creating, no problem occurs and the relationship is OK. However, when updating, this strange exception comes up. My entities are setup like this:

```
class Ticket
{
    // ...

    /**
    * @var TicketCategory
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TicketCategory")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $category;

    // ...
}

class TicketCategory
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $title;

    // ...
}
```

Form

```
class TicketType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', 'text', array(
                    'error_bubbling' => true,
                )
            )
            ->add('category', 'text', array(
                    'error_bubbling' => true,
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Ticket',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 4):

Problem is:

```php
    $builder
        ->add('category', 'text', array(
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            )
        )
    ;
```

Field `category` is declared of type "text", thus you can pass only scalars (string, bool, etc) to it. That is you can only specify properties (of `Ticket` class) that are scalars.

In `Ticket` class `category` it's an entity, so the error occurs.

Without knowing what you want to accomplish, i guess you want to make the user choose a category for the ticket, so i'll do:

```php
    $builder
        ->add('category', 'entity', array(
                'label'    => 'Assign a category',
                'class'    => 'Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\TicketCategory',
                'property' => 'title',
                'multiple' => false
            )
        )
    ;
```

More on [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

**EDIT**: don't know if you omitted it, but `Ticket` has no property named "title".

Comment: It has to be text, this is not a common form. It's a RESTful webservice. I'm converting the text field value from a string (which is the category ID) into an object using $em->getRepository('ApiTicketBundle:TicketCategory')->find($request->request->get('category));

That has nothing to do with the problem, since it CREATES the entity perfectly, and also makes the relationship. It just fails to UPDATE.

Comment: @vinnylinux so, are you using a http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html? Anyway, you have to be more specific in your question... with the code posted by you, the error IS the field itself (if you are not using transformers).